# Best way to find a tag among an array of tag objects in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-tagging and I've got an array of tag objects. What's the best way to determine whether a given tag is among them?

```
def is_new (self):
    tags = Tag.objects.get_for_object(self) 
    tagged = False

    for tag in tags:
        if tag = 'new':
            tagged = True

    return tagged
```

Comment: For one thing, your code won't run right:  `if tag = 'new':` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: Right. I was typing too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never really used django tagging but looking through the source really quickly the .get_for_object returns a queryset of the tags for that object. Not an actual list.

I'm not sure if your code is working [appart from the assignment/comparison issue] or if you just want to improve it. But Since you are returning a queryset couldn't you continue filtering it for instance:

```
Tag.objects.get_for_object(self).filter(name='new')
```

or to be able to use JamesO's example of:

```
if 'new' in tags:
   return True
```

I think you need to turn the queryset into a list first.

```
list(tags)
```

And then it should work.

See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) for forcing list evaluation - and note the memory concerns of doing that.

So my recommendation would be testing filtering first - and let us know if it works, because now I got curious.

Comment: Your suggestion was spot on and seems to be more efficient than forcing list evaluation. I tried tags=list(Tag.objects.get_for_object(self)) followed by JamesO's suggestion, but it didn't evaluate True. Though maybe I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
tags = Tag.objects.get_for_object(self) 

if 'new' in tags:
    return True
```

Comment: For some reason, that's not evaluating as True when I have given the object a tag of 'new'.